# Converting Unicode back to JavaScript escapes

Tags: javascript

Supoose we pass `\u001B\u001A\u0019\u0018\u0017\u001E`, it should return us the arabic characters.

[Here](http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/) is a tool.

Comment: Could you perhaps add more tags or explanations to this post?

Answer (score 0):

Just evaluate the string as a string literal:

```
var decoded = eval('"' + str + '"')
```